# How to write correct way of sql query in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to fetch all data from this table for that i am using query :

```
      $emp = Employee::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->first();

    $holidays = Holiday::orderBy('holidays.id', 'desc')->take(5)->where('holidays.id', '=', $emp->id)->get();
```

It is not giving me any result. I am new to php can anyone help me out yrr?

[image: Holiday Table]

Comment: I think you want `where('holidays.created_by', '=', $emp->id)`, because `holidays.id` should be unique, not tied back to the employee id.

Answer (score 3):

The "eloquent" way to do it would be in your Employee model to set up the relationship between Employees and Holidays :

```
public function holidays() { 
    return $this->hasMany(Holiday::class);
}
```

and then in your Holiday model set up the reverse :

```
public function employee() { 
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'created_by');
}
```

Note that we're having to pass over the name of the foreign key explicitly as it's not what Laravel is expecting (employee_id).

Then you can just load your Employee :

```
$emp = Employee::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
```

and then access their holidays :

```
$holidays = $emp->holidays;
```

or :

```
$lastfiveholidays = $emp->holidays()->take(5);
```